# How fix broken text in my menu and broken img

Tags: html, css

I've been sitting here for an hour and I can't figure it out. I can't create a normal horizontal menu.
I have 2 problems.

1. the logo is cropped for some reason.
2. the menu, which has a space, is not lined up in a row, but connected in a column. And if you remove the space, it becomes a string. How do I make all menu items in one line and at the same time adaptive?

```css
.header {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  min-height: 40px;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1950px;
  padding: 20px 0px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.header__body {
  transition: 0.3s;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.header__main {
  display: inline-flex;
}

.header__menu {
  display: inline-flex;
}

.header__logo {
  width: 100%;
  /* Ширина области */
  height: 70px;
  /* Высота области */
  margin: 0;
}

.int42h {
  width: 100%;
  /* Ширина изображений */
  height: 100%;
  /* Высота изображении */
  object-fit: cover;
  /* Вписываем фотографию в область */
}

.menu__list {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0;
}

.menu__item {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  position: relative;
}

.menu__link {
  font-size: 26px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: inherit;
  transition: color 0.3s ease;
}

.header__login {
  padding: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header__container container">
  <div class="header__body">
    <div class="header__main">
      <div class="header__logo">
        <img src="assets/img/logo.png" alt="" class="int42h">
      </div>
      <div class="header__menu">
        <nav class="menu__body">
          <ul class="menu__list">
            <li class="menu__item"><a href="" class="menu__link">SCHOOL</a></li>
            <li class="menu__item"><a href="" class="menu__link">ORGANISATION</a></li>
            <li class="menu__item"><a href="" class="menu__link">UNIVERSITY</a></li>
            <li class="menu__item"><a href="" class="menu__link">COURSES LIST</a></li>
            <li class="menu__item"><a href="" class="menu__link">BLOG</a></li>
            <li class="menu__item"><a href="" class="menu__link">FOR US</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "menu is not lined up in a row, but connected in a column."? Do you mean the logo and the menu are not lined up?

Comment: no, I have a menu item in which there are 2 words(For us) that are not on the same line, but words on top of each other.

And another part of the logo is cut off

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent the text in links from splitting into multiple lines, set `width: max-content` on `menu__link` class. That should fix the logo as well, if not then remove `width: 100%` on `header__logo` or change it to `auto`. Usually with images, when you are setting an explicit width or height, you should let the other one stay auto.